# Some post share on facebook didn't show up images

Tags: posts, facebook

My site can share the post to Facebook. However, the features images cannot show up. I had check all my meta-tag which require by Facebook is there. Can anyone help to find out the problems?
Link: [www.master-insight.com](https://www.master-insight.com)

Answer (score 0):

When posting a link, there is an option to upload a photo / image? hope this is what your query is?

Here’s how this works all:

1. You need the ability to access the HTML on the particular webpage you are sharing. It'll probably work site wide too if you use a common header file. I have not tried this, but it should work. You'll just get the same image for all pages if you do this though.
2. You need to add these HTML meta tags into page in the . It will not work if you put it in the . Make sure to customize per your a) image, b) description, c) URL, and d) title.

A Real Example.

3. Save
4. Open a fresh Facebook post, and retry the page you wanted to share.
5. If you are having trouble… you can debug it with this Facebook tool. It looks more geeky than it is. It tells you what Facebook is seeing when you post in the URL to share.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Big Tip.. make sure the “quote marks” are the same in your HTML (they should look like 2 straight marks and no curves… sometimes programs change these to different fonts and it goofs up the code.

by John Wayne